# Remote C++ Development using SSH only inside Eclipse Environment

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How do you integrate Remote Systems Explorer and CDT plugin inside eclipse ?

What I mean is that you can use Remote Systems Explorer (RSE) plugin to work on C++ code on a remote linux box inside Eclipse but when you try to compile, you basically run a shell command through SSH. The CDT plugin is unable to locate the remote system and off course the remote compiler.

Is there a way to integrate both the plugins so that we can use the parsing / suggestion features of CDT for the remote system as well; and also features like remote compilation, remote debugging using SSH only. If this is not possible, then what is the closest open source alternative to the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know how to integrate the plugins you mentioned I do something similar to what you want to achieve on a daily basis with SSH's X forwarding.

If the remote box has X libraries installed and you have a local X server running, you can just `ssh -CXY ...` into the development box and simply run eclipse (or any other X application) there. The process will live on the remote box and, therefore, have access to all the filesystems and tools, but the GUI elements and those alone will be displayed in your local X session. That, though, may require quite a bit of bandwidth. Please see `man ssh` and X documentation for security stuff and compression settings.

Comment: Same here, and if the bandwidth is too small for ssh -X, you can use QTNX that starts a new Linux session on the remote box.

Answer (score 0):

The PTP project is building a [remote build for CDT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/designs/remote/cdt). Not sure how good that works, but you could always use the Terminal view from RSE to manually call your remote build (make).

Comment: Thats wat I have been doing but debugging there is not possible as CDT is unaware of wats going on ..

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it myself, but maybe you could try NetBeans and see if it works for you.
According to page https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html it has everything you need, even

> [...] system includes, macro definitions, platform, etc. All of this information is gathered from the remote server and stored locally on your client system, so that when you edit locally the code assistance will work even when the project is set up to use a remote build host.